# How to stick two UITableView section headers to the top of UITableView one above another while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

UITableView can have section headers and by default when you scroll the table view then the section header will stick to the top. In my table view I will have sections/cells with years and months and I want to stick both year section/cell and month section/cell to the top together. For example tableview will have rows:

```
2010
 january
  something1
  something2
 february
  something1
  something2
2009
 feb
  something1
  something2
 march
  something1
  something2
  ...
```

and when I scroll down I want both cells:

```
2009
 march
```

to stick to the top of the table view one above the other. How to solve this problem?

[image: two sections on top]

Comment: Have you got any solution?